# Uninstalling QGIS that was installed using OSGeo

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo

I installed QGIS using OSGEO4W, and would love to know how to uninstall it, because when I go to "Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall" the program does not appear in the list of installed programs.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 93):

Just to elaborate on the comment on the above answer that `It appears that the uninstall option no longer exists in the osgeo4w.exe installer`.  As of today, there *is* an option to uninstall but you have to play chicken as if you're going to install because the uninstall option doesn't appear until quite late in the install process. I ran `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\osgeo4w-setup.exe`

See screenshots:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5. Note, although not shown here I did uncheck the `Hide obsolete packages` checkbox to make sure I was uninstalling as much as I could. Then click where it says "Default" this will cycle through various options.  Keep clicking till it says "Uninstall"

[image]

6.

[image]

After that you can simply remove the `C:\OSGeo4W64\` folder to remove installer files.

Comment: am just confirming that this method is still valid for the 64bit version that i downloaded the exe for on 8th of Septmeber 2020.....It doesn't remove all items, such as C:\osgeo4w folder still has a lot of content (about 5MB) and shortcut icons still persist, but otherwise, the method above works.

Comment: Worked with QGIS 3.1 on 9-Jan-2021

Comment: Still working: 09-Sept-2021

Comment: Still working march 2022

Comment: Still working: 18/08/2022. Thanks for this workaround.

Comment: I am wondering: Is this "uninstall" option taking care of everything, e.g. AppData/UserData, StartMenu entries/shortcuts, PATH entries, registry entries? Or asking differently: What is the upside vs. just removing the folder or using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352028/34517) answer?

Comment: still working: january 2024

Answer (score 32):

There is not a best way to do it, no 'Add Remove Programs' method. But...

The simplest way is to delete C:\OSGeo4W. This will remove all the installed data. You can also uninstall stuff through the osgeo4w.exe installer.

(From the website:http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/FAQ)

> Is there a way of uninstalling packages or all of OSGeo4W?
>
> Individual package can be uninstalled via the Advanced install path. In the package listing click on the "New" column until the value changes to "Uninstall". Currently packages do not clean up desktop or start menu icons when uninstalling, this may be done manually.
>
> Currently there is no installer option to uninstall OSGeo4W completely. However, when all OSGeo4W applications, shells and services (like apache) are shutdown it is possible to just delete the whole OSGeo4W file tree (usually C:\OSGeo4W).
>
> See also trac #38 (enhancement).

Comment: I assume there are no registry settings created by OSGEO if just deleting the directory is expected to work properly. Is this accurate?

Comment: There is a registry entry under HKLM/Software/OSGeo, which will not be removed by deleting the folder. But this does not bother any other installation. I would recommend the Uninstall option in the installer as mentioned above.

Comment: It appears that the uninstall option no longer exists in the osgeo4w.exe installer, the advice on the FAQ remains the same, but there's no sign of an uninstall option under Advanced Install. So I think deleting is now the only option.

Comment: Just a note that the comment by @EddyTheB isn't (now?) accurate. Individual components within the installer can be uninstalled as noted above. Uninstalling using the installer (although selecting 'uninstall' for all components) does not remove all content from the OSGeo4W folder or delete this. I've had success in re-setting an installation that was messed up by using the installer to uninstall all components, then also deleting the folder afterwards. I didn't test a simple folder deletion on its own. There may well have been better options. (All testing of this on Windows).

Answer (score 15):

Might add to the above entries with my current complete-removal workflow:

1. Delete `C:\OSgeo4w64`
2. Delete `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OSGeo4W`
3. Delete `C:\Users\%USER%\documents\grassdata`
4. Delete `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\QGIS`

There will also be a shortcuts folder on your desktop to delete. There may be other app-specific folders to clear (edits welcome if so), but the above should cover the express install.

If you have admin control and have set any OSGeo related system or user environment variables in Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables... (or via a shell command) you should also remove those, and tidy up your PATH variable. Be careful not to remove PATH entries or other variables that point to non-OSgeo versions of OSGeo packages you may still have installed, e.g. ArcMap's python distro, or a standalone version of GDAL.