# I cannot find osr after installing OSGeo4W package

Tags: gdal, osgeo, osgeo4w

I wanted to be able to import OSR from GDAL on my Python 2.7 (Anaconda) Windows 7 64-bit. I installed OSGeo4W after reading [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows) and eventually I'd like to import osr

```
from osgeo import osr
```

However, I cannot find any osgeo or osr after installing osgeo.

The other option would be installing GDAL from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) but it says that "Do not use together with OSGeo4W".

How can I import `osr` after installing OSGeo4W?

I downloaded 64 bit version under **Quick Start for OSGeo4W Users** from https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki not from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython. Perhaps that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because OSGeo4W installs its own local Python site, there are certain environment variables that must be set to use it.  The simplest way to do this is by running the "OSGeo4W Shell" and then running python from the resulting command line.  Alternatively, you can inspect the "OSGeo4W.bat" batch file in the root of your OSGeo install folder for ideas about how to roll your own script.

Comment: So I found "OSGeo4W.bat" and it has bunch of text in it. Should I modify this file? Is that what you mean by rolling the script? Thanks

    \@echo off
    rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the same directory this script exists      in
    call "%~dp0\bin\o4w_env.bat"

    rem List available o4w programs
    rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
    \@echo on
    \@if [%1]==[] (cmd.exe /k o-help) else (cmd /c "%*")

Comment: No.  Simply run the file to get a command line where you can run your Python scripts or the interpreter.  Understanding the script will help you if you ever want to automate the startup of a Python program.

Comment: Great. So after running the file, I see bunch of stuff like gdal_calc, gdal_edit, etc. and then "GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10". A command "C:\OSGeo4W64" shows up. I am trying to import ogr but I am not in Python environment. I guess I don't have any clue what to do with it!

Comment: I also don't see any sign of ogr or osr in OSGeo4W64 folder. There are stuff like grass and qgis, but not osr. Maybe I installed the wrong package?

Comment: Sorry if confusing.  At the command prompt (after all the gdal_calc, gdal_edit stuff) you can enter the command `python` to use an interactive python session, or enter something like `python myscript.py` to run a script you have already written. (This assumes the script is in the current directory.)

Comment: Ok, I see. It totally works. I can import osr from osgeo. Now, I have my Python 2.7 installed somewhere else and use Spyder to edit my Python scripts. Is there a way to change the configurations so that I can import osr from there? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

So after installing OSGeo4W, another Python has been installed on my system. My previous Python was 2.7.10 and this new one (in OSGeo4W folder) was 2.7.5. So, I completely erased OSGeo4W package following [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30990/how-can-i-uninstall-quantum-gis-that-was-installed-using-osgeo) and the new installed Python was removed as a result. Then, I followed instructions on [this page](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/) exactly and managed to install osgeo package. It doesn't come with **qgis** and other softwares but I didn't need them anyways.