# QGIS not launching

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, qgis-2.18, osgeo4w

a few days ago I decided to update my QGIS 2.14 into a QGIS 2.18.

I uninstalled the old version and installed the new one, normally.
Then nothing at all happened when I pressed the icon.

I uninstalled, deleted all registry mentioning old installations of QGIS, reinstalled 2.18, and still nothing.

I tried installing **QGIS OSGEO4w**, but again, nothing.

I changed the **Qgis.bat** to add the system folder

> PATH %systemroot%\system32; %systemroot%; %systemroot%\system32\wbem

, and nothing..

I really don't know!

Clearly I also tried to install back the 2.14, but it does not launch either.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried running the `qgis.bat` file or loading the OSGeo4W Shell and typing in `qgis`?

Comment: yes.. not even the OSgeo shell is launching, actually..

Comment: Might I suggest starting again: uninstall QGIS, delete the `.qgis2` folder (located in `/Users/You/.qgis2`, back up any scripts or models if you made any), if using Windows run the **regedit** program and delete everything related to QGIS. Restart your computer then do a clean install using the correct QGIS setup (32-bit or 64-bit). See if this helps. You shouldn't need to modify any paths, it's weird nothing seems to load.

Comment: I tried this several times, actually, and it didn't work at all. I don't know why. Furthermore, now that I have installed everything through OSGeo4W I don't even have the uninstal option!

Comment: Please make sure you uninstall your osgeo4W install via the osgeo Setup  : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/256500/25139

Comment: Update: I uninstalled OSGEO in a proper way, deleted everything using Regedit that was mentioning QGIS, GRASS or OSGEO itself. Reinstalled QGIS 2.14 and NOTHING. SAGA not starting, QGIS not starting, nothing at all. Actually this time I don't even have the qgis.bat file.. I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the OSGEO folder, including all the installed applications. (This is usually installed at C:/).

If you do this, and then run the most recent OsGeo4W installer and install again, that should sort it.

Comment: Thanks. I installed already everything using the latest OsGeo4W installer, and yet nothing was starting..

Comment: Is your OS 32 or 64 bit? What version of the installer did you use?

Comment: It's a 64bits. The installation through OsGeo gave some error at the end, but I don't know what exactly. I'm going to try again now. I downloaded the latest version a couple of days ago but I cannot read the version.

Comment: You'd better take note of the error, hey!