# How to properly uninstall OSGeo4W+GRASS+QGIS on Windows7 64bit

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, windows-7, remove

Over the years I have tried QGIS and other mapping systems.  Lately I wanted to make a go at using the newer versions of QGIS but wanted the ability to run the new one, 3.4 or 3.6 and to keep the old LTR 2.18 running parallel.  I read that is possible through OSGeo4W.

Something went wrong in a DL or install and now I have versions of GRASS growing all through my Win7 64 bit system. (Growing Grass was a joke..) but GRASS is install all over in different versions, as is QGIS.

One helpful post suggested just deleting the normal C:\OSGeo4W directory.

I have tried just about everything and for my trouble, I have folders and files all around and they do not work or they error. (Although I must have deleted something else because now I can't produce an error, just nothing happens.

How can I clean this up?
In searching it looks like there is no uninstall facility listed.
ultimately I want to start clean with a new install.

Comment: Some have told me there are hidden files in Roaming, but I cannot seem to get rid of OSgeo to reinstall fresh everything!

Comment: I know I'm a bit late but, basically, [this old gis.stackexchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30990/uninstalling-qgis-that-was-installed-using-osgeo) is still the answer.